# Как портировать программу с ncurses из под линукса на винду с MinGW?

Tags: c++, linux, mingw, ncurses

Написал программу на с++ на линуксе с использованием ncurses. Хочу перекомпилировать ее с помощью MinGW, но, я так понимаю, нужна pdcurses, чтобы все нормально работало. Как скачать pdcurses на линукс и как откомпилировать программу с pdcurses с MinGW ?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77126/discussion-on-question-by-neo-----ncurses---).

Answer (score 1):

1. Установить [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) и обновить пакеты до актуальной версии;
2. Через консоль msys2 установить ncurses: `pacman -S ncurses`;
3. Через консоль msys2-mingw32 (или msys2-mingw64, если нужна 64-х битная сборка) собрать свой проект аналогично тому, как вы делаете это под Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется нашел решение:

https://pdcurses.sourceforge.io/

Скачиваете отсюда, распаковываете, все хэдеры перемещаете в папку с инклюдами для mingw, после чего заходите в папку `wincon`, открываете `Makefile` и меняете там компилятор с `gcc` на `i68..`-как-то там - сами разберетесь. У меня компиляция полностью не прошла, но библиотека `pdcurses.a` скомпилировалась. Переименовываете на `libpdcurses.a` и кидаете в папку `lib` для mingw. Все. У меня работает.

Comment: "При установке выбираете элементы: компилятор g++, make, pdcurses (все элементы что содержат это название) и msys с соответствующими расширениями." Эти элементы надо выбрать при установке MinGW?

Comment: @neo не обязательно при установке. Если `mingw` уже установлен, просто сново запускаете установщик и выбираете нужные элементы

Comment: а какой командой запускается установщик и как выбрать элементы?

Comment: @neo Товарищ явно предполагает, что вы собираете под windows.

Comment: @neo вы устанавливали mingw с помощью mingw installer? Если да, то просто его запускаете

Comment: Нет я качал его просто командой

Comment: @VTT neo ведь писал, что хочет собрать проект под windows, странно было бы это делать под другой операционкой

Comment: @neo что-то я не понял, как вы скачали его под windows?

Comment: это странно, но это так)

Comment: я под линуксом делаю

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Ничего странного тут нет, это называется кросс-компиляция.

Comment: @neo я понял, что вы написали программу в линуксе, но вот только как вы собираетесь на линуксе скомпилировать ее под винду? Вы под вином это делаете?

Comment: я хотел использовать вайн для проверки работы программы, а компилировать вроде без вина можно

Comment: @neo с этим, если честно, я не знаком. Я просто переносил код на виртуалку, где компилировал его на windows с помощью mingw. Не знал, что можно сделать это в линуксе

Comment: Все равно спасибо

Comment: То есть везде, где в Makefile используется gcc поменять на i686-w64-mingw32?

Comment: а все разобрался)